# Any reliable site where *hardware* engineers can be hired for small (work-from-home/telecommute) projects?

Tags: untagged

For software hackers/developers there are many.

However, I need a hardware guy (or girl?) for a relatively small project.

Is there a site where I can search for people and see ranks, recommendation, etc.?

Comment: btw, what kind of small jobs are we talking about here? just curious.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6263/what-kind-of-skills-as-electronics-engineer-are-marketable-for-small-freelance-wo/6270#6270

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Elance.com](http://www.elance.com) and [iFreelance.com](http://www.ifreelance.com) both have listings for hardware engineers.  Elance is far larger, and currently has over 8500 providers listed under Electrical Engineering.  I am listed under both and have gotten work through them in the past.

Another one suggested by a comment below is [freelancer.com](http://www.freelancer.com), formerly known as getafreelancer.com.

Comment: i'd add www.freelancer.com to the list also.

Comment: @Mark, I'm a member at freelancer.com also.  I tried searching for Electrical Engineering and only came up with a couple of listings, which is why I left them out.  But if you go to their home page and scroll down to Engineering & Science, turns out there are quite a few jobs listed (19, plus 28 under Electronics).  So I was mistaken.  I don't know how to search providers there however.  On iFreelance.com, when you search providers for Electrical Engineering you get 62 hits.

Comment: agreed their search isn't as good when using the term "electrical engineering" most of the jobs that would interest folks from this board fall under "electronics" or similar headings.

Comment: @mark, @tcrosley, elance seems to be the only site that when I am actually writing proposals it seems worth it.

Answer (score 5):

Try: http://www.adafruit.com/jobs/