# electronic freelancing website

Tags: pcb-design, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any reliable site where *hardware* engineers can be hired for small (work-from-home/telecommute) projects?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7186/any-reliable-site-where-hardware-engineers-can-be-hired-for-small-work-from-h)

I want to outsource couple of industrial electronics circuit design and development, what are the resource (website) to do so.

my requirement is mostly circuit design / pcb design and two or three development/optimization cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Adafruit has a [job board](https://www.adafruit.com/jobs/) aimed at makers and engineers.